# NFS Mounting Error

Tags: rhel, mount, nfs

From ServerA I shared directory `/u001/app/oracle/FolderA` and trying to mount this on SeverB under `/media`

Contents of ServerA `/etc/exports` file

```
/u001/app/oracle/FolderA      ServerB(rw,sync)
```

When I try to mount it on ServerB I receive this message on ServerB

```
mount: mount to NFS server 'ServerA' failed: timed out (retrying).
mount: mount to NFS server 'ServerA' failed: timed out (retrying).
mount: mount to NFS server 'ServerA' failed: timed out (retrying).
mount: mount to NFS server 'ServerA' failed: timed out (retrying).
mount: mount to NFS server 'ServerA' failed: timed out (giving up).
```

`rpcinfo -P` output:

```
program vers proto   port
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp    953  status
    100024    1   tcp    956  status
    100011    1   udp    924  rquotad
    100011    2   udp    924  rquotad
    100011    1   tcp    927  rquotad
    100011    2   tcp    927  rquotad
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100021    1   udp  13495  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  13495  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  13495  nlockmgr
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100021    1   tcp  15597  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  15597  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  15597  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp    938  mountd
    100005    1   tcp    941  mountd
    100005    2   udp    938  mountd
    100005    2   tcp    941  mountd
    100005    3   udp    938  mountd
    100005    3   tcp    941  mountd
```

`/var/log/messages`:

```
Oct 28 17:16:21 kernel: nfsd: last server has exited
Oct 28 17:16:21 kernel: nfsd: unexporting all filesystems
Oct 28 17:16:22 kernel: NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Oct 28 17:16:22 kernel: NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
Oct 28 17:17:28 mountd[4143]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting.
Oct 28 17:17:29 kernel: nfsd: last server has exited
Oct 28 17:17:29 kernel: nfsd: unexporting all filesystems
Oct 28 17:17:29 kernel: NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Oct 28 17:17:29 kernel: NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
Oct 28 17:21:15 kernel: FS-Cache: Loaded
```

Any help will be awesome......

Comment: you can try the command "service nfs restart" once.

Comment: NFS ports open on ServerA's firewall?  What's  the output of exportfs on ServerA?  What's the output of 'showmount -e ServerA' from ServerB?

Comment: Can you show us the exact command you use to mount the NFS share? Are you defining it manually or via `fstab`?

Comment: I used sudo mount -t nfs ServerA-IP:/u001/app/oracle/FolderA /u001/app/oracle/DestFolder. But later I checked the port 892 was not open i think it was the cause. After opening the port I restarted the NFS and it started working

Answer (score 1):

Try using the IP address instead of the ServerA/ServerB. From the [RHEL docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Storage_Software_Appliance/3.2/html/User_Guide/ch14s04s06.html):

*excerpt*

```
14.4.6. mount command fails with NFS server failed error.

mount command fails with following error:    
mount: mount to NFS server '10.1.10.11' failed: timed out (retrying).

Perform one of the following to resolve this issue: 

Disable name lookup requests from NFS server to a DNS server.

The NFS server attempts to authenticate NFS clients by performing a reverse DNS
lookup to match hostnames in the volume file with the client IP addresses. There
can be a situation where the NFS server either is not able to connect to the DNS 
server or the DNS server is taking too long to responsd to DNS request. These 
delays can result in delayed replies from the NFS server to the NFS client 
resulting in the timeout error seen above.

NFS server provides a work-around that disables DNS requests, instead relying 
only on the client IP addresses for authentication. The following option can be 
added for successful mounting in such situations:

    option rpc-auth.addr.namelookup off
```

So based on your error message I think your having an issue with the servers not being able to resolve each other's via their hostnames.